# Qual maneira correta de utlizar reverse(); num determinado elemento id

Tags: javascript

Tenho no document HTML um determinado *elemento* que tem números ordinais do 0 a 9.

Estou tentando usar o método `reverse();` para inverter a ordem dos numeros no meu elemento. A lógica deveria ser:

1- capturar a saída(out) do *elemento* `id`, que esta numa *tag* `<span>`
2- fazer a inversão de 9 - 0
3- voltar a colocar no elemento.

## Codigo de Tentativa

```
<script>
window.onclick = function(){
    var listar = document.getElementById('txt');
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML   = listar.reverse();
}
</script>

<body>
    // Aqui No corpo do documento HTML
    <span id='txt'>0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguns problemas no teu código:

a) Quando usas `listar.reverse();` esse listar é um elemento, e imagino que precises do `.innerHTML` do elemento.

b) As strings não têm o método `reverse` quem o tem são as Arrays. Assim tens de criar e "descriar" uma array para inverter esse texto.

c) O teu `<script>` não está nem no `body` nem no `head`. Talvez tenha ficado assim para o exemplo, mas deve estar dentro de um deles.

Podes fazer tudo assim:

```
window.onclick = function() {
  var listar = document.getElementById('txt');
  listar.innerHTML = listar.innerHTML.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kr0v10ax/